# What is the TCP error of a `ConnectException`?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have some Java code that connects to a Windows application a virtual machine (VirtualBox) over a bridged WLAN adapter. The strange thing here, is that this works "sometimes", and when it starts working, it works for some time, and then stops again.

The code has been working fine for years, it is just this combination of mobile terminal (it's Android) and virtualised server that is b0rking on me:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
connection.setDoOutput(true);

// 'tel' is the String I am sending
connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(tel.getBytes().length);
connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
connection.setReadTimeout(requestTel.getTimeout());

// this call throws the exception
OutputStream o = connection.getOutputStream();
```

The exception I am getting from the Java code is this `ConnectException`:

> java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /192.168.3.145:8080

According to the documentation, this *can* be when no process is listening (there is), but apparently this can also mean routing is incorrect or something else. I would like to know the underlying TCP error, so I can troubleshoot this better.

(When connecting to the service from the virtual host, it connects fine. When connecting from the mobile terminal to the host (emulating the service), it connects fine. After re-trying several times, it works for a limited time (it's almost like there is a firewall that needs kicking through and is rebuilt after a minute or so).)

**Update** when connecting my virtual guest to a wired port, it seems to work fine...

Comment: I think what it actually means is that the attempt to connect timed out.  *Why* it timed out could be anything, such as the list of reasons you gave.  You have to investigate your own network to determine what is going on.

Comment: @markspace, no, a timeout throws a `SocketTimeoutException`.

Comment: Sounds like an issue I had in the past. Unfortunately I was never really able to solve it concretely. Have you created a port forwarding rule for the port 8080 on the VM? Settings->Network->Adapter#->Port Forwarding. Also for some reason when i would rearrange my adapters for VirtualBox on the VM, start up the VM, shut it down, then rearrange them back it would work.